# How to get date field group by result in single row

Tags: postgresql

I have records like below screenshot
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IacHk.png)

I want result like,
if date is between 1st to 15th date of particular month then return count as Month15,
if date is between 16th to 30th date of particular month then return count as Month30

expected result like :

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-2-1 to 2023-2-15 | 0 |
| 2023-2-16 to 2023-2-28 | 3 |
| 2023-3-1 to 2023-3-15 | 1 |
| 2023-3-16 to 2023-3-31 | 2 |

In sort, I get count of 15 days interval in POSTGRESS Database

Thanks,

I have tried using group by query but it return duplicate results

Comment: Can you edit your question and share simple data as text not image, so it can be easy for us to help you ?

Answer (score 0):

The following example is intentionally verbose for illustration:

```
with limits as ( -- Determine starting and ending months
  select min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
    from my_table
), months as ( -- Generate month series and explode to month halves
  select gs.month_start, o.offset_start, o.offset_end
    from limits 
         cross join lateral 
           generate_series(
             date_trunc('month', start_date),
             date_trunc('month', end_date),
             interval '1 month'
           ) as gs(month_start)
         cross join (
           values (interval '0 days',  interval '15 days'),
                  (interval '15 days', interval '1 month') 
         ) as o(offset_start, offset_end)
), ranges as ( -- Create tsrange column
  select tsrange(
           month_start + offset_start, 
           month_start + offset_end
         ) as bucket
    from months
) -- Join back to data, aggregate, and create labels
select concat(
         lower(r.bucket)::date,
         ' to ',
         (upper(r.bucket) - interval '1 day')::date
       ) as "Date", 
       count(t.date) as "Count"
  from ranges r
       left join my_table t on t.date <@ r.bucket
 group by bucket;
```

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fnoocnD2)

Comment: Thanks @Mike Organek, if i want result in single row then how is it possible with above query

Comment: @DeepPatel  What are you talking about?  The results match your expected results.  If you want to pivot the results, then ask a new question.